# do windows azure mobile service scripts have transient fault handling

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

When I access a SQL table via the server scripts is the sql azure retry logic implemented somewhere following the 
`request.execute();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the underlying code will try several times to complete the operation with SQL Azure over a 30 second window.